# Sanitize INSERT SELECT sql using Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

How to do I sanitize this sql using Zend Framework, so that I can prevent sql injection attack?

```
"INSERT INTO table(A, B, C)
 SELECT MAX(A)+1, '".$params['B']."', '".$params['C']."' FROM table
 WHERE B='".$params['B']."' AND C='".$params['C']."'"
```

$params['B'] and $params['C'] are user inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Use QuoteInto method to sanitize it.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.quoting.quote-into

To sanitize multiple arguments,

```
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this->_name . ' WHERE (a = ? AND b = ?) OR (c != ?)');
$stmt->execute(array($a, $b, $c));
```

http://blog.motane.lu/2009/05/21/zend_db-quoteinto-with-multiple-arguments/

Comment: What's the difference of using $this->_db->prepare($sql) instead of new Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo($this->_db, $sql)?